# Why does Exception take Throwable as a constructor parameter instead of Exception?

Tags: java, constructor, exception, class-design

I noticed recently that `Exception` has several constructors which take `Throwable` as a parameter. `Throwable` has two subclasses, `Error` and `Exception`, and generally all documentation indicates that you should not attempt to catch or handle an `Error`. Therefore, I am curious why `Exception` takes a `Throwable` as a constructor parameter instead of an `Exception`. This implies that an `Exception` could be created with an `Error` as its cause and could be handled by the application. Why is this the case?

Should custom `Exception` classes then only provide constructors that take `Exception` as parameters?

Comment: Just guessing: maybe sometimes people still try to log exceptions somehow; and maybe that is easier if you use some of your own custom type exceptions; and so you allow for such things to be wrapped around a Throwable. Or maybe, the language papas and mamas just didn't think that one through.

Comment: JAVADoc syas: *"An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such errors are abnormal conditions."* But it does not forbid you from catching them.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it's basically because:

1. it's not recommended to handle an `Error` but it's **not forbidden**.
2. it's a good practice to program to the interface anyway, so the parameter type should support the widest range of types by having it as the root interface `Throwable`.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, `Exception` class constructors accept `Throwable` as a parameter because some libraries or APIs might need to create their failure type that extends `Throwable`, and then your failure handlers would need to be able to deal with those as well.

Also, you can `throw` a `Throwable` and not necessarily an Exception. This makes it easy to throw something that is a custom type of program failure, and hence it will have its unique level of **recoverability**.

For your custom `Exception` classes, I think it depends on the granularity you want when handling failures. The convention would be gracefully handled `Throwable`s. This is because even though you may not be able to recover from an error, you may still want to notify users that it happened.